# Make containing elements ishittestvisible = false while contained elements are ishittestvisible = true

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering if it were possible to make the parent container `IsHitTestVisible = false` while having `IsHitTestVisibile` for the children as True AND still be able to access the children. Right now this what I have tried and of course it doesn't work.

Example:

```
<Grid IsHitTestVisibile= "False">
  <Button IsHitTestVisibile = "True"/>
</Grid>
```

My reasoning behind this is that I am changing the style of my data-grid headers to include a drop down (Pop-up control) list of all the available filters. However when you click in the white/empty space of the Pop-up control it causes the Header to be clicked and the data to sort. So If I could only make the actual elements used for filtering to be hit test visible I could eliminate the problem.